# Can your Phantom make skill checks while in your subconscious?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, occult-magic, spiritualist

The Spiritiualist's Phantom resides in the Spiritualist's mind while it isn't manifested, and it has its own mental stats separate from yours, so could the phantom attempt its own mental skill checks separately from you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## An unmanifested phantom probably can't make skill checks

The [spiritualist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/spiritualist)'s supernatural ability [shared consciousness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/spiritualist#TOC-Shared-Consciousness-Su-) describes the extent of the spiritualist's [phantom](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/spiritualist#TOC-Phantom)'s effect on the spiritualist himself when the phantom's not fully manifested.

Any effects *beyond* those described by the special ability shared consciousness would have to be adjudicated by the GM. As rules *already* exist that describe the benefits of an unmanifested phantom, persuading the GM that there should be *even more* benefits—like the spiritualist being able to make a bunch of duplicate skill checks because there's a ghost in his head—may be difficult. Good luck.